# How to find correct artifact id for a spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I started working with spring and I'm using maven.

I want to work with [JMX support that spring provides](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jmx).

I'm trying to include the dependency using maven. And for the same I went to [mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com) and searched for spring. But I see a lot of projects with different artifact-id and I'm not sure which one should I start using and include as a dependency in my `pom.xml`.

I expected that I'd find this information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/), but I didn't.

Is there a centralized place for spring where I could always go and find what is the artifact-id that I need to choose. I think I'm missing something obvious here.

In short my question is that say if I want to use spring's `MBeanExporter` is there any formal procedure to know that it is imported via `spring-context`?

Simply searching for the package name don't work `org.springframework.jmx` gives me a dependency of `spring-jmx`. Now I don't know what to use `spring-jmx` or `spring-context`

Answer (score 0):

If you're still using spring 2.x then you probably want spring-jmx if you're using spring 3.x, 4.x or 5.x I believe the "org.springframework.jmx" package is provided as part of spring-context. Certainly if you look at the latest javadocs for spring-context(https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework/spring-context/5.1.3.RELEASE) the "org.springframework.jmx" package is included.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful!